# (neovim) nvim_win_get_cursor() gets same value after nvim_input("<CR><Esc>")?

Tags: neovim

I'm trying to set a key map like

```
local key_map = vim.keymap.set
local input   = vim.api.nvim_input

local opts = { noremap = true, silent = true }

key_map('n', '<C-j>', function()
                        local desired_cursor_col = tonumber(vim.api.nvim_win_get_cursor(0)[2])                        
                        input('i<CR><Esc>')
                        local new_line_start_col = tonumber(vim.api.nvim_win_get_cursor(0)[2])
                        
                        print(desired_cursor_col, new_line_start_col)  -- (*) Tried to check the values

                        input('i')

                        for j = 1, (desired_cursor_col - new_line_start_col) do  -- (**)
                          input('<Space>')
                        end

                        input('<Esc>')
                      end, opts)
```

But the mapping seems to skip the for-loop labeled by `(**)`

(I tried to check the value at `(*)` but the mapping does not print the values. Weird.)

Do I miss something or make some mistake? Thanks.

Comment: I think the reason why `(*)` for-loop does not work is that `desired_cursor_col` and `new_line_start_col` are the same.

Comment: By the way, this mapping is used in the such case that the code is composed of the following lines: `    @fn funcName(varType varName, -- indented by four spaces.` and `        
       varType va|rName) -- indented by 15 spaces to align the first line` where `|` is the cursor. 
In normal mode, press `<C-j>`, then cursor `|` will be in the third line and its column position will be exactly under where it was in the second line, and the string `rName` now will follow the cursor.
Hope this can help understanding my question.

Comment: I have a doubt about `input` being a local variable used in a global mapping. Did you tried with `vim.api.nvim_input` instead?

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt Yes, Even though I use `vim.api.nvim_input()` in the function and `vim.keymap.set()` for setting the mapping, it skips the for-loop `(*)` (which can be verified by commenting out the last line `input('<Esc>')` and after typing `<C-j>` we will be in insert mode).